# Apache Camel mock endpoint

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel

I recently started to investigate Apache Camel and I have one issue.
I start writing some test for my routes, and there are a lot of examples, where "to" part of route is written as

```
    <route id="person-add-route">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
```

So, I wrote a test, where I am exepcting to have mock:result as last endproint.

```
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void testCamel() throws Exception {
    // Given
    Object body = "body";
    int messageCount = 1;
    MockEndpoint endpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");

    // When
    template.sendBody("direct:start", body);

    // Then
    endpoint.expectedMessageCount(messageCount);
    endpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Here is the questions: Is this important to write **mock:result** if I want to test my route??

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...are you asking if you need to include a mock endpoint at the end of all your routes in order to test them?

Comment: I am asking - do I need to include that "mock:result" in my production routes? If yes, that's quite confusing for me, because I don't understand why I need to add test functionality in my real code? Is there any way, where I can exclude that "mock:" directive in my real code ? 
It's not a problem for me to make a workaround, but I would like to get some more elegant solutions.
Thanks,

Comment: You do it wrong, you should set the expectations before you send a message. 1) set expectations 2) send message 3) assert is satisifed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to include "mock:result" in production, there are multiple ways to test your route. One is to implement `isMockEndpoints` in your Camel test:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpoints()
{
     return "*";
}
```

So if your route is like this:

```
<route id="person-add-route">
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="direct:result"/>
</route>
```

You can check the MockEndpoint like this:

```
MockEndpoint endpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:direct:result");
```

You can also use [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) to modify your route at test time, by doing something like this:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {
         weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
    }
});
```

Also, as Claus mentioned in his comment, make sure you set your expectations before you send your message to the route.

Comment: Hi, actually, I tried your solution, and it's not working, I'm receiving DirectConsumerNotAvailableException - no consumers available on endpoint.

Comment: You need to replace `direct:result` with whatever your actual endpoint needs to be. Direct endpoints need a consumer by default. I was just using it here as an example.

Comment: The official Apache Camel website is probably the best resource. Claus Ibsen's [Camel in Action](http://www.manning.com/ibsen/) book is a very good reference as well but I'm not sure how up-to-date it is.

Answer (score 5):

The above (and currently accepted) answer is very old and probably not very accurate anymore. To implement a similar approach today could look something like this:

Given a route defined as a spring component:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:start").routeId("myRoute")
            .setBody().simple("${body} world")
            .process(exchange -> 
                exchange.getIn().setHeaders(Map.of("foo", "bar")));
    }
}
```

Then the route can be tested as follows:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

import static org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.adviceWith;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
class MyRouteTest {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @Produce("direct:start")
    private ProducerTemplate from;

    @EndpointInject("mock:result")
    private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @Test
    void testMyRoute() throws Exception {
        // arrange
        adviceWith(camelContext, "myRoute", 
            route -> route.weaveAddLast().to("mock:result"));
        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        // act
        from.sendBody("hello");

        // assert
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        var result = mockEndpoint.getExchanges().get(0).getIn();
        assertThat(result.getBody()).isEqualTo("hello world");
        assertThat(result.getHeader("foo")).isEqualTo("bar");
    }

}
```

So what `route.weaveAddLast().to("mock:result")` basically does, is weaving a last step to your route that will redirect the message to mock:result.

Comment: Nice! exactly what i needed